# What is the preferred way to generate HTML tag in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html

I have the following code in Ruby on Rails 3. What is the preferred way to set the class (or id) to the value of a variable, and output it?

`<%= tag "td", :class => @priority_level %><%= @priority_level %></td>`

Outputs:
`<td class="normal">normal</td>`

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The content_tag helper is sometimes visually more appealing than intermixing Erb and HTML:

```
<%= content_tag(:td, @priority_level, :class => @priority_level) %>
```

There are also other templating options out there besides the default Erb.

Here's the equivalent in [Haml](http://haml-lang.com/) :

```
%td{:class => @priority_level}= @priority_level
```

and [Mustache](https://github.com/defunkt/mustache):

```
<td class="{{priority_level}}">{{priority_level}}</td>
```

I think that both are easier on the eyes than Erb. If you're stuck in Erb-land, organizing your code into helper methods and partials as much as possible is a good way to keep Erb templates visually manageable.

Answer (score 4):

Generally for this I would define the tag like this:

```
<td class="<%= @priority_level %>"><%= @priority_level %></td>
```

There's no reason to make Rails do more work than it really needs to do.

Comment: That just seemed a bit clunky and redundant...I thought maybe there is a better way...

Comment: If you find this clunky and are looking for a more-code-like solution, you might find [haml](http://haml-lang.com/) more to your taste.